# mysqlworkbech 6.1 how to apply inserts data changed

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, mysql-workbench, modeling

iam new to mysqlworkbench. i am using the latest 6.1 version of it. While iam designing model(EER diagram) i created a table and tried to insert some default data to it in the bottom inserts tab of the respective table. [image]

now when i try to close the bottom tab i get a pop up for saying to apply the changes, but i cant find the apply button anywhere on the GUI , Please help where is the apply button so that i can apply
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's an apply button on the toolbar:

[image]