# MySQL Workbench - Apply Changes icon in Inserts tab not responding when clicked

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MySQL so this might be a very simple question.  I'm trying to add new data to an existing table in the MySQL Model in the Workbench using the "Inserts" tab.  I can enter the data with no problem, but when I click the "Apply Changes" icon nothing seems to happen.  No script is generated, the table isn't updated, nothing.  I've been digging around reading through the Oracle manual, looking through Stack Overflow, watching YouTube videos, you name it, and can't find an answer as to why it doesn't respond.  It does look like there was a bug that got fixed years ago (MySQL Bug #54456) that was the same or very similar to the issue I'm having.  I'm unable to attach images at this point, please ask me if you need any clarification.  Thanks!

Since I can't post a screenshot please see this link for a very similar problem.  When I click on the green "Apply Changes" icon nothing happens.  [mysqlworkbech 6.1 how to apply inserts data changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475909/mysqlworkbech-6-1-how-to-apply-inserts-data-changed)

Comment: No Screenshot visible!!

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't allow me to attach an image.

Comment: I added a link in my question that gives a screenshot with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late but what you insert in that tab it's only for when you do a forward engineering of the model, also you must check the box that says generate INSERTS statements for tables when doing it.
Have a great day.